# update column based on matching row values in other columns with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, isin

I need to replace the value in columns ending in _4 with an updated value based on what value they include in the other columns. if the first 3 columns contain 1, the fourth should be zero. if the first three columns contain zero, then the fourth column should be 1.

in my code below, I want to assign this counts var to have the same name as the common column (i.e. a or b) - and then replace the x'_4' column in the original dataframe with this new counts column
However its also not counting correctly, as the counts for a and b are currently. any comments welcome. Thankyou

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'a_1':[1, 0, 0, 0],
                    'a_2':[0, 0, 0, 1],
                    'a_3':[0, 0, 0, 0],
                    'a_4':[1, 0, 1, 1],
                  
                    'b_1':[0, 0, 0, 1],
                    'b_2':[0, 0, 0, 1],
                    'b_3':[1, 1, 0, 0],
                    'b_4':[0, 1, 0, 1]})
```

my current code look like this

```
out = []
counts = []

col_list = ('a','b')

for col in col_list:

    
    d = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith(col)]
    dat = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.endswith('4')]
    counts = dat[(dat.isin([1]).any(1).astype(int))|(d.isin([1]).all(0).astype(int))]
    counts^=1
    counts_df = pd.DataFrame(counts)
    out.append(counts_df)
```

the overwritten columns in the original dataframe should look like this

```
    a_4 b_4
0   0   0
1   1   0
2   1   1
3   0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try via `filter()` and get column names like `'_4'`:

```
cols=df.filter(like='_4').columns
```

Finally:

```
df[cols]=(df.filter(regex='_[0-3]')
            .rename(columns=lambda x:x.split('_')[0])
            .groupby(axis=1,level=0).sum().eq(0).astype(int))
```

output of `df`:

```
        a_1     a_2     a_3     a_4     b_1     b_2     b_3     b_4
0       1       0       0       0       0       0       1       0
1       0       0       0       1       0       0       1       0
2       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       1
3       0       1       0       0       1       1       0       0
```

Comment: thanks so much thats really useful. Is there a pythonic way to deal with the column names though, rather than specifying with regex in the command? I have tried to separate them with specifying this before hand ```all_cols = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.endswith('4')].columns``` and then add as df.filter(all_cols) but it throws an error that columns must be same length as key in some cases

Comment: @b101 For your method use `df[df.columns[~df.columns.str.endswith('4')]]` this replaces `df.filter(regex='_[0-3]')`